# Ajax response type is text/html, how to get response type of application/json?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have specified Ajax response on server side as:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

When I check after my request completion, I get the following response header:

```
Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

In my response, I am sending the following status based on whether the request got completed successfully or failed or there is an exception.

```
if($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
    // Create SQL Statement
    foreach ($payload_jsonDecoded as $i => $item) {

        $sql = $sql . "some insert query";
    }

    // Prepare statement
    $insertstmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // execute the query
    $insertstmt->execute();


    if($insertstmt->rowCount() > 0){
        $json = json_encode(array(
            "status" => true,
        ));
    }
    else{
        $json = json_encode(array(
            "status" => false,
        ));
    }
}
else{
    $json = json_encode(array(
        "status" => false,
    ));
}

echo $json;
die();
```

On client side, I am using:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'path',
            type: "POST",
            data: jsonObj,
            //dataType: "jsonp",
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              success: function (output, status, xhr) {
                  console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
```

My logic as well as code works, but on the client side, my response contains the following messages which messes up the response message and hence I am not able to display correct message to the end users.

```
Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0
```

Any insights would be grateful.

Comment: I have tried to setup 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1'  in php.ini and that does not seem to work. For warning message, I am not sure.

Comment: *"I have specified Ajax response on server side as:"* where in relation to your other php code? it seems as though you may be trying to do it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use the php header

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Before you actually echo the content

*i see you use this already but it should work

Answer (score 0):

Old post but if anyone comes by this, the problem is you are echoing "echo $json;"

Server thinks it's string format, try returning it instead or send json response back back to ajax.